# how to pull the shipping price from banggood.com using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i'm trying to get the shipping price from this link:
https://www.banggood.com/Xiaomi-Mi-Air-Laptop-2019-13_3-inch-Intel-Core-i7-8550U-8GB-RAM-512GB-PCle-SSD-Win-10-NVIDIA-GeForce-MX250-Fingerprint-Sensor-Notebook-p-1535887.html?rmmds=search&cur_warehouse=CN

but it seems that the "strong" is empty.
i've tried few solutions but all of them gave me an empty "strong"
i'm using beautifulsoup in python 3.
for example this code led me to an empty "strong":

```
client = requests.get(url, headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"})
soup = BeautifulSoup(client.content, 'lxml')
for child in soup.find("span", class_="free_ship").children:
    print(child)
```

Comment: I don't see any shipping prices listed on the page.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the 'Free Shipping' is generated by JavaScript after the page loads, rather than being sent in the webpage.

It might obtain the Shipping price by performing a HTTP request after the page has loaded or it may be hidden within the page

You might be able to try to find the XHR Request to pulls the Shipping price using DevTools in Firefox or chrome using the 'networking' tab and using that to get the price.

Answer (score 0):

Using the XHR, you can find that data:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

url = 'https://m.banggood.com/ajax/product/dynamicPro/index.html'

payload = {
'c': 'api',
'sq': 'IY38TmCNgDhATYCmIDGxYisATHA7ANn2HwX2RNwEYrcAGAVgDNxawIQFhLpFhkOCuZFFxA'}

response = requests.get(url, params=payload).json()

data = response['result']

shipping = data['shipment']
for each in shipping.items():
    print (each)

print (shipping['shipCost'])
```

**Output:**

```
print (shipping['shipCost'])
<b>Free Shipping</b>
```

Comment: sp there is no way to get the shipping price with beautifulsoup?     and about your url, when I try to open it I get error 404 (page not found) , and when I replace it in your code with my url I get run-time exception, why is that?

Comment: that url is ajax request and needs to be accompanied with the query parameters. You can't just pop that into you browser to return the data, nor can you replace it with your specific url (they are different). However, it MAY be possible to get that shipping cost. I'll take a look in a few minutes to see if it's possible.

Comment: just checked and no you will not be able to get the shipping cost straight out of requests from your URL and beautifulsoup. As stated below, it's javascript generated. Now sometimes that data is imbedded in `<script>` tags in the html source, but tht's not the case here. Your only options are a) use the method I used by requesting the XHR which is where the site fetches that data, or b) use something like Selenium to allow the html to render first (and then you could use beautifulsoup). That however is dependant on the attributes of the tags, and if they are dynamic, is not robust

Comment: about option b, if i'll just sleep for few seconds would I be able to pull it with beautifulsoup??            how can I get this "strong" with selenium?

Comment: no. To simply use sleep wouldn't work with requests (don't be confused with pulling the html source and parsing it). Beautifulsoup has nothing with obtaining the html, it works with pull data out once you have html source.. You'd have to use selenium. I'll work on a selenium solution this morning and post it back here.